# Как привязать свойство readonly к input, которое будет зависеть от чекбокса?

Tags: angular

Доброго времени суток!

Пытаюсь сделать реактивную форму, в которой один из инпутов может иметь свойство readonly в завсимости от состояния чекбокса - если чекбокс выбран, инпут доступен для ввода текста, если не выбран, инпут ридонли.

Компонент:

```
import {FormControl, FormGroup, Validators} from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-topic',
  templateUrl: './add-topic.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-topic.component.css']
})
export class AddTopicComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  addTopicForm: FormGroup;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.initForm();
  }

  initForm(): void {
    this.addTopicForm = new FormGroup({
      'tabName': new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      'indicatorName': new FormControl(null, Validators.required)
    });
  }
}
```

Шаблон:

```
<form class="addTopic modal"
      [formGroup]="addTopicForm">
    <div class="project-label">Добавление топика</div>
    <div class="controls form-group">
      <label for="tabName">Название</label>
      <input type="text"
             id="tabName"
             formControlName="tabName">
      <label for="indicatorName">Индикатор</label>
      <span><input type="checkbox" id="isIndicator" #isInd checked></span>
      <input type="text"
             id="indicatorName"
             [readonly]="!isInd.checked"
             formControlName="indicatorName">
    </div>
</form>
```

Собственно, так вроде работает, но свойство readonly ставится от балды через раз (вне зависимости от состояния чекбокса, надо несколько раз сменить состояние чекбокса еще и сам инпут потыкать, чтобы у него появилось нужное свойство). Что я делаю не так?

Comment: оно не "ставится от балды", это свойство вовсе не отслеживается, поэтому конструкция `isInd.checked` бесполезна, используйте `ngModel`

Comment: @overthesanity ну вообще удивительно, т.к. у инпута все же ставится ридонли. тогда не знаю, почему оно ставится там.

так а разве использование ngModel в реактивных формах не deprecated?..

Support for using the ngModel input property and ngModelChange event with reactive form directives has been deprecated in Angular v6 and will be removed in Angular v7.

Comment: `type="checkbox" id="isIndicator" #isInd` у вас без `formControlName`

Comment: хм, логично, благодарю! пойду осваивать дальше